# How to end a thread in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am new to perl and i have a question about perl thread.

I am trying to create a new thread to check if the running function is timed out, and my way of doing it is as below.

Logic is 
1.create a new thread
2.run the main function and see if it is timed out, if ture, kill it

Sample code:

```
$exit_tread = false;      # a flag to make sure timeout thread will run
my $thr_timeout = threads->new( \&timeout );  
execute main function here;                

$exit_thread = true       # set the flag to true to force thread ends
$thr_timeout->join();      #wait for the timeout thread ends
```

Code of timeout function

```
sub timeout
{

$timeout = false;
my $start_time = time();
while (!$exit_thread)
{

    sleep(1);                 
    last if (main function is executed);

    if (time() - $start_time >= configured time )
    {
        logmsg "process is killed as request timed out";
        _kill_remote_process();
        $timeout = true;   
        last;         
    }
}    
}
```

now the code is running as i expected, but i am just not very clear if the code $exit_thread = true works because there is a "last" at the end of while loop.

Can anybody give me a answer?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us a short, complete working example, using `strict` and `warnings`.  "true" and "false" aren't Perl-isms, and I don't quite follow why you ask about *threads* but show code excerpts referring to *remote processes*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that the correct pseudo code is this:

```
sub timeout
{

$timeout = false;
my $start_time = time();
#$timeout instead of $exit_thread 
while (!$timeout)
{

    sleep(1);                 
    last if (main function is executed);

    if (time() - $start_time >= configured time )
    {
        logmsg "process is killed as request timed out";
        _kill_remote_process();

        $timeout= true;   
        last;         
    }
}    
}
```

Then, no, calling `last` will not set the `$timeout` variable - it will simply leave the loop from the point of calling it.

Is this answering your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what i meant to say is the variable "$exit_timeout", the purpose i set it is to make sure the timeout thread will be terminated when it's not needed. But as you see, i put a "last" at the end of while loop to make sure the timeout thread will be terminated either the main function is executed or timed out, that means timeout thread is finished even before i set the "$exit_timeout" to "true". So just wondering if the "$exit_timeout" is needed.

Comment: what do you mean by variable `$exit_timeout`? there is no such variable in your code